Installshield installscript how to return custom return code?
Installshield - Installscript project
Anyone can share how to generate custom return value from installscript actions/function ?
I would like to override the return value or add my custom return value in installscript. For installscript (setup.exe) to return the custom return value. Then user can use a batch file(.bat) file to check each fail case by %errorlevel%.
So after checking the document about return value. it seems not much about this portion. Installshield Return Value
All the document shows the default return value return by setup.exe.
As a result that I can not find a way to generate my own return value.

I try to check the Copilot and it said to add "SetExitCode(123)" in "OnEnd()" event. But I can NOT find the "SetExistCode()" from the Installshield's help document. (So compiler error is expectped)

I try to add "return -2" in "OnAbort()" function. then use a batch file (.bat) to run my setup.exe and check the %errorlevel%.  But it still return the default error code (defined by installshield). It still can not return my return value (-2) to %errorlevel%.


Step1. Create Installscript project from Installshield
Step2. Installscript to add custom even "OnAbort" "OnSetTARGETDIR" "OnBegin"
Step3. Add "abort;" to "OnSetTARGETDIR()" function to trigger "OnAbort"
Step4. Add "Return -2;" to "OnAbort()" function
Step5. Build and generate "Setup.exe"
Step6. Write my test.bat.  "c:\test\setup.exe"
step7. check errorlevel . add "echo %errorlevel%" to test.bat
step8. run test.bat in command prompt. and check the echo errorlevel
P.S The Installshield -> Start Page -> Media -> Releases -> Release 1 -> Setup.exe -> Custom Return Code ->Set to "Yes". ( Do Not know how to return error code during Cancel/Abort.)
